# Sorting server side data with Vuetify Datatable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to sort data on a loaded Vuetrify data table from a server-side resource.

```
<template>
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-text-field
                    append-icon="search"
                    @click:append="getsearch"
                    hide-details
                    label="Search"
                    single-line
                    v-model="search"
                ></v-text-field>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-data-table
                :headers="headers"
                :items="outputs"
                :pagination.sync="pagination"
                :rows-per-page-items="rowsPerPageItems"
                :total-items="totalOutputs"
            >
                <template v-slot:items="props">
                    <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.title }}</td>
                    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.journal.title}}</td>
                    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.created }}</td>
                </template>
                <template v-slot:no-results>
                    <v-alert :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
                        Your search for "{{ search }}" found no results.
                    </v-alert>
                </template>
            </v-data-table>
        </v-card>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        //TODO add in url sorting parameters for the VUE = https://codepen.io/retrograde/pen/pmzQNP?editors=1010
        data() {
            return {
                rowsPerPageItems: [25, 50, 100],
                isLoading: true,
                totalOutputs: 0,
                pagination: {
                    rowsPerPage: 100,
                    descending: false,
                    sortBy: "name",
                    page: 1
                },

                search: '',
                headers: [
                    {
                        text: 'Title',
                        align: 'left',
                        sortable: false,
                        value: 'title'
                    },
                    {text: 'Journal', value: 'journal', sortable: true},
                    {text: 'Published On', value: 'created', sortable: true},
                ],
                outputs: []
            }
        },

        watch: {
            pagination: {
                handler() {
                    this.fetchData();
                },
                deep: true
            }
        },
        methods: {
            fetchData() {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const {sortBy, descending, page, rowsPerPage} = this.pagination;
                    let search = this.search.trim().toLowerCase();

                    this.$http
                        .get(
                            "api/output?page=" +
                            page +
                            "&rowsPerPage=" +
                            rowsPerPage

                        )
                        .then(response => {
                            console.log(response.data);
                            let outputs = response.data.data;
                            const totalOutputs = response.data.total;
                            if (search) {
                                outputs = outputs.filter(item => {
                                    return Object.values(item)
                                        .join(",")
                                        .toLowerCase()
                                        .includes(search);
                                });
                            }

                            this.outputs = outputs;
                            this.totalOutputs = totalOutputs;
                            this.loading = false;
                            resolve();

                        });
                });

            },

            getsearch(){
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const {sortBy, descending, page, rowsPerPage} = this.pagination;
                    let search = this.search.trim().toLowerCase();

                    this.$http
                        .get(
                            "api/output?page=" +
                            page +
                            "&rowsPerPage=" +
                            rowsPerPage +
                            "&title=" +
                            search
                        )
                        .then(response => {
                            console.log(response.data);
                            let outputs = response.data.data;
                            const totalOutputs = response.data.total;
                            if (search) {
                                outputs = outputs.filter(item => {
                                    return Object.values(item)
                                        .join(",")
                                        .toLowerCase()
                                        .includes(search);
                                });
                            }

                            this.outputs = outputs;
                            this.totalOutputs = totalOutputs;
                            this.loading = false;
                            resolve();

                        });
                });
            }


        },
        mounted() {
            this.fetchData();
            this.getsearch();
        },
    }

</script>
```

I'm thinking that I would have to configure my API with URL parameters to allow sorting?

I've seen some examples of Vuetrify which has static data which can sort, but I don't seem to be able to make it apply to data which I've gotten through my API

Or is there a way to sort the already loaded data?

Comment: Your question title is different than what you are asking in the description. Are you looking for examples of server side paging or sorting on the client (already loaded)?  Please reword to ask one specific question with appropriate code (your example lacks the script piece)

Comment: The question (and title) seems a little confused. If you want to sort on client side, then it has nothing to do with your API (provided it is supplying the data you request). Your pagination *should* order it, but I haven't tested it myself. Maybe an initial sort is required? In your `fetchData()` method, why not add `.sort()` to the fetched array and sort it as it comes in?